# Catching ICMP reject on UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, packet-capture, icmp

Firewalls such as IPtables have the option to notify the sender (after blocking a packet) via ICMP messages (e.g. Port closed). This message contains the header of the rejected packet (required by a RFC), so it's technically possible to associate it with the application that sent it.

**Is there any easy way to programatically capture ICMP messages related to my application in a unix environment?** It would be convenient if the application could tell the user that the destination is probably behind a firewall. It doesn't have to be POSIX specified, but it shouldn't be limited to only one platform (although I would like to know about it anyway :).

One way to achieve this would be with raw sockets and another one is using pcap, but both of these are quite invasive and I would have to go through all the ICMP messages and filter the ones that belong to other applications.

Comment: Huh? You should be already be receiving an error which depends on the ICMP type: ENETUNREACH, EHOSTUNREACH, ENOPROTOOPT, ECONNREFUSED.

Answer (score 0):

> it's technically possible to associate it with the application that sent it

I doubt there's an *easy* way to do what you want.  The kernel receives the ICMP message and processes it before telling the program it was unsuccessful.  For example, here's the result of pinging an unreachable host (running on Linux using `strace` to examine the system calls; the boldface line is the result of receiving an ICMP error):

```
    sendmsg(3, {msg_name(16)={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.113.198")}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\10\0mQ\f\24\0\1~u\227U\0\0\0\0\250\373\1\0\0\0\0\0\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27"..., 64}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 64
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={10, 0}}, NULL) = 0
    recvmsg(3, 0x7ffffd6ecbe0, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    recvmsg(3, {msg_name(16)={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.113.206")}, msg_iov(1)=[{"E\0\0008\5\316\0\0\200\1\366q\300\250q\316\n\0\2\17\3\0017\335\0\0\0\0E\0T\0"..., 192}], msg_controllen=32, {cmsg_len=32, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=0x1d /* SCM_??? */, ...}, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 56
    recvmsg(3, 0x7ffffd6ecbe0, 0)           = -1 EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
    recvmsg(3, {msg_name(16)={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.113.198")}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\10\0mQ\f\24\0\1", 8}], msg_controllen=80, {cmsg_len=32, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=0x1d /* SCM_??? */, ...}, msg_flags=MSG_ERRQUEUE}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_ERRQUEUE) = 8
    write(1, "From 192.168.113.206 icmp_seq=1 "..., 61) = 61
    write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
    write(1, "--- 192.168.113.198 ping statist"..., 40) = 40
    write(1, "1 packets transmitted, 0 receive"..., 73) = 73
    write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
```

You could run your application and monitor `strace` (or the like on your system), but then you'd have to watch for and decode all the various ICMP failure modes.  This is going to be pretty invasive.

Comment: So the recvmsg() call sets errno to EHOSTUNREACH if an ICMP  Destination Unreachable message is received?

Comment: Essentially yes.  Have a look at [the Linux source code for ping.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/ping.c), lines 546-556

Comment: That doesn't really make it clear... You reference a function that seems to process an ICMP message, which is pretty much what I asked. However, I have no clue who calls this function...

Comment: I was totally off-base.  See @ninjalj comment above.  That tells you everything you need to know: in your application, when you call a network function, you should check the return value.  See the `connect (2)` man page, for example, under the "ERRORS" section.

Comment: Yeah, now it makes sense. But is it possible to get those error codes for e. g. UDP messages?

Comment: According to the `udp(7)`, `socket(7)` and `ip(7)` man pages, yes.  In particular, the `udp` man page says, "All  errors documented for socket(7) or ip(7) may be returned by a send or receive on a UDP socket."  `ip` man page enumerates these.  Note that you want to enable `IP_RECVERR` to get enhanced error reporting for connectionless (e.g. UDP) sockets.